# Should I buy separate devices for router/modem? If I do, would ISP have access to router firmware?

Tags: router

I own a router/modem combo (an Arris/Motorola).  I have noticed that every time I change ISPs, the login interface of the router changes.  I think this is because the ISPs push different versions of the firmware to the device. I wanted to ask:

1) If I switch to a dedicated cable modem coupled with a dedicated router, will the ISP be able to mess with the router?

2) Is the setup in (1) more secure in general?

Thanks!

Comment: The ISP should not be able to do anything to YOUR router

Comment: Thanks!  Do you think the firmware changes are a coincidence?  I have a router that went from Motorola to Arris to Motorola and back to Arris and it seemed to coincide with ISP changes.  Thanks and sorry if this is a weird question!

Comment: No worries. If it is the ISP that have given/lease you the router, they may do automatic changes to it. But if you bought the router, your ISP should not be able to do anything to your router without you given them access. Firmware changes may happen automatically by the router itself, but if your ISP have given you the router, they may do it.

Comment: You might consider buying an older name-brand firewall appliance to put between the router and the modem.  At least that will protect you from unsolicited traffic from outside.  They are available for very good prices these days.